# Is this a good reasoning? That 3D Universe is shadow of 4D Universe

Tags: philosophy-of-science, physics, universe

It may sound crazy but, in this 3D world there is nothing 2D, other then our shadow. Is it good to say that the shadow of 3D object is 2D, then shadow of 2D object would be 1D. 
Hence this 3D universe is shadow of 4D world?

Comment: Place yourself between the sun and an object that is not totally flat, say a cylinder. You will see that your shadow is not in 2D, but can be a 3D surface: you can trace a line linking two points of your shadow, that does not touch any third point.

Comment: I didn't get your reasoning. I put moon between sun and earth and the shadow of the moon i am getting is still 2D i don't understand how it can be a 3D surface shadow has no thickness how it can be a 3D surface? @armand no matter how shadow bends it will be 2D correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Furthermore, the shadow of a 2d object is not necessary 1d. If you hold a piece of paper (an approximately 2d flat object) perpendicular to the rays of the sun, its shadow will be 2d.

Comment: see that's the problem the piece of paper is approximately 2d not actually 2D that's what i said the true 2D thing in this 3D world is only the shadow or a 3D object

Comment: please consider a sphere: it has no thickness, yet it is definitely a 3d surface. You can't represent a sphere on a piece of paper. No thickness is not equivalent to 2 dimensional.

Comment: the thickness of the paper is not the problem here. 2d surfaces projected perpendicular to themselves produce a 2d image. Unless projected on a line, but then, anything projected on a line results in a 1 dimensional segment anyway. I also have to stress the point that 2d figures with 0 thickness, cast no shadow...

Comment: you might be right but as far as i understand how do we define dimensions is, 0D is like nothing kinda black hole or something, a point which is like singularity is 1D now if we put so many points of that singular point it will become a line and then so many lines on that line will become plan 2D and then so many plans on that plan will become cube 3D object.

Comment: @armand can you please let me know then how do we define the dimensions? or can you please let me know the object which has 0 thickness so if i will put that perpendicular to sun it will project no shadow that i understood but there is no such object i know other then shadow

Comment: i would really like to know what is the problem with the question, I request you to please tell me the reason for downvote. Thanks !!

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Your analogy is metaphorical, which is a method by which we understand things. External reality no more possesses dimensions than the sky is blue or the grass is green. I'd start with an article on [embodied cognition](https://plato.stanford.edu/search/searcher.py?query=embodied+cognition).

Comment: Thank you @JD I have been using stackoverflow more than an year i already took the tour. Did you Downvoted my question?

Comment: Nope. I did vote to close it. Generally, open ended metaphysical speculation is discouraged here. The intent of the forum is to provide specific, referenced answers to clear, well-articulated questions.

Comment: @JD can you please tell me where i can ask such questions do we have specific meta site for such questions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105264/discussion-between-j-d-and-raman-mishra).

Comment: Wouldn't the 4D world just be a shadow of a 5D world? And wouldn't that 5D world just be the shadow of a 6D world?

Comment: @user253751 what’s the point? That’s what I was saying

Comment: You stopped at 4D.

Comment: you know induction right? if that's true other will be true still @user253751what's the point?

Comment: So we actually live in a 235857623414123D world that is just a shadow of a 235857623414124D world?

Comment: @user253751 there can't be more than 11 dimensions please if you don't have any thought on that don't waste my time :D

Comment: @RamanMishra but a 11D world is just a shadow of a 12D world.

Comment: @user253751 yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you think a shadow is, probably not.

If you think a shadow is a boundary, then no. The boundary of a boundary is null. It's not one dimension less, it's the empty set.

https://jeffycyang.github.io/the-boundary-of-a-boundary-is-null/index.html

If you think a shadow is a projection, then also no. Projections have the property that if you perform the projection again, then you get back the original projection. That is, if P is the projection operator, then P * P = P. Or, to take a specific example: If your chair is 45 cm in the "x" direction, then length of the "x direction" of your chair is also 45 cm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

The only possible way it could make sense is as a cross section. The intersection of a cone with a plane is circle, ellipse, parabola, or hyperbola. If you "fill in" this figure you get a segment of a plane. Then the intersection of this with a line is a line segment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(geometry)

The problem with that is, it presumes there is already a plane to intersect the cone. You need to define both the plane and the cone apart from their intersection.

So, supposing there is a 4D universe that we are a cross section of is, so far, not helpful. You need to define this 3D universe, and the 4D universe, both independently. And once that is done you need to define the intersection that gives the cross section. And, so far, you have done none of that.

So, no, what you are saying isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Even now, when you assert that this is 3D world, you are ignoring 'Time'. In other words, we are observing this world 'from' a 'time-based' world. The fact is that we can't even assert that this is 3D world. Time plays tricks on us like a magician.

Comment: ok so if this is not 3D universe then what it is? and are you the downvoter? And out universe in on space time plan right so there will be time in other universes but that doesn't answer my question but thanks for pointing out Time. As far as i understand about time is just a concept it has something to do with universe but not sure with dimensions

Comment: No, I give down-votes very very rarely. How could I **explain** about another dimension standing on a time-based world?

Comment: Imagination may be i don't know you can tell me something nobody knows think there is no time i don't know i just thought that and asked a question and it might be a silly one.

Answer (score 0):

The Universe cannot be regarded as 3D as it is factually wrong. To imply that a time slice **now** is like a picture in 3D is equivalent to saying that there time is experienced in between quantum jumps of planck time ticks. Makes absolutely no sense, because time isn't a concept at the planck scale. After planck time, the Universe changes quantum states. That's about it. Time at higher levels is emergent from this activity of change of quantum states in planck time. Between two states, there is no **now**. This misconception, if abolished, clears the air and we now see that what you call now, is not there. There is no "planck frame" which is like frozen in time.

The idea is persistent because of the block universe model. In that model it is supposed that for an observer, the block universe is like a loaf of bread, but this bread, isn't cuboidal. Rather it progressively skews as you'd like to make a slice of "now". This is because there is no universal now that all observers agree to. So a distant universe, will not agree on the simultaneity of events, and subsequently, of "now". Hence you are left with your unique perspective.